# Oracle simple SQL query result in: ORA-08103: object no longer exists

Tags: sql, oracle

please help with a query on Oracle. I'm using SQLPlus (but with SQLDeveloper is the same) to accomplish a simple query like:

```
select count(*) from ARCHIT_D_CC where (TYP_ID=22 OR TYP_ID=23) and SUBTM like '%SEP%' and CONS=1234
```

This is a very simple query that works perfect until I'll execute it on a big table that contains tons of data. After a few minutes I got:

> **ERROR at line 1: ORA-08103: object no longer exists**

This because the database is partitioned and due to large ammount of data in the table and before my query finishes, oracle BT mechanism rotates the table partitions. That's why I got the message.

Now, is there a way to avoid this error? Maybe specify the partition or something like that. As already wrote, in other table with less data, it works perfect.

Thanks
Lucas

Comment: What does "BT" stand for here?  How is the table partitioned?

Comment: WOPS! You're right! :P
It's Business Object (BT = Business Tool). However this is a simple query from shell using SQLPlus. The supplier explain that there's a mechanism that rotates the table partitions, that's why after a few minutes I got this error because query took time due to large ammount of data.

Comment: What does it mean to "rotate the table partitions" and why would that happen every few minutes?  That seems exceptionally odd

Comment: Honestly I just reported the explanation from supplier, I'm a simple Oracle user not the admin :-). I cannot change that behaviour and supplier doesn't provide me other info other than what I have already reported. My question is, knowing the behaviour that can't be changed, is there a way to avoid the query stop with the reported error? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Without knowing what's going on, it's probably impossible to come up with a solution that would ensure the query would run short of doing something crazy like replicating the data to a different structure.

Comment: Rotating the partitions every few minutes is indeed very odd. Having said that, you can query a specific partition by using a colon between the name of the table and the name of the requested partition. The trick is to make sure the partition you query from contains the data you're looking for. Try to query from user_tab_partitions to find out the requested partition name and then use "from table_name:partition_name" to avoid your error. Good luck.